# Change default document layout when generating word document from OpenXML in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I've been able to generate a simple word document using a format similar to the format used in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194646/create-word-document-with-open-xml), however whenever I open the document it opens in print layout view. Is there a way that I can programmatically make it open in web layout view by default?

Comment: I'm guessing this can be done using OpenXML.WordProcessing.View but I'm not sure at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by using a [`OpenXML.WordProcessing.View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.view%28v=office.14%29.aspx). You need to create a [`View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.view%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with its `Val` set to `ViewValues.Web`. Then you need to create a [`Settings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.settings%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object and append the `view` to it. Finally, you need to create a [`DocumentSettingsPart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.documentsettingspart%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and set its `Settings` property to the `settings` object you've created.

That sounds worse than it is, below is a complete method taking the code from the [question you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194646/create-word-document-with-open-xml) plus code for the above. I've removed the memory stream code from that answer to simplify things; this code will create a file on disk.

```
public static void CreateWordDoc(string filename)
{
    using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        // Add a main document part. 
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

        // Create the document structure and add some text.
        mainPart.Document = new Document();
        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
        Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
        run.AppendChild(new Text("Hello world!"));

        //the following sets the default view when loading in Word
        DocumentSettingsPart documentSettingsPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<DocumentSettingsPart>();
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        View view1 = new View() { Val = ViewValues.Web };
        settings.Append(view1);
        documentSettingsPart.Settings = settings;

        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }
}
```